# Python - how to find string and remove string plus next x characters

Tags: python-3.x, string

I have the following string:

`mystr = '(string_to_delete_20221012_11-36) keep this (string_to_delete_20221016_22-22) keep this (string_to_delete_20221017_20-55) keep this'`

I wish to delete all the entries `(string_to_deletexxxxxxxxxxxxxxx)`  (including the trailing space)

I sort of need pseudo code as follows:

If you find a string `(string_to_delete` then replace that string and the timestamp, closing parenthesis and trailing space with null e.g. delete the string `(string_to_delete_20221012_11-36)`

I would use a list comprehension but given that not all strings are contained inside parenthesis I cannot see what I could use to create the list via a string.split().

Is this somethng that needs regular expressions?

Answer (score 0):

it seemed like a good place to put regex:

```
import re

pattern = r'\(string_to_delete_.*?\)\s*'

mystr = '(string_to_delete_20221012_11-36) keep this (string_to_delete_20221016_22-22) keep this (string_to_delete_20221017_20-55) keep this'

for match in re.findall(pattern, mystr):
    mystr = mystr.replace(match, '', 1) # replace 1st occurence of matched str with empty string

print(mystr)
```

results with:

```
>> keep this keep this keep this
```

brief regex breakdown: `\(string_to_delete_.*?\)\s*`

1. `\(` look for left parenthesis - escape needed
2. match string `string_to_delete_`
3. `.*?` look for zero or more characters if any
4. `\)` match closing parenthesis
5. `\s*` include zero or more whitespaces after that

Comment: Thank you. In practice I will need to delete the found strings programatically - so as a non regex user how to I go about parsing/interrogating the Match object to extract the range for each iteration in order to delete the range? Is there a method?

Comment: i've simplified the solution not to using match objects. if you don't want to use regexes you can use `while loop` and `index()` to navigate through the string, but i've found this solution with regexes not necessarily more optimal but faster to write

Comment: @MrDave did you try?